# How do I use dired-read-file-name in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was looking for a method to show a list of filenames in a directory, and then select one of them.

I found this:
https://github.com/lawlist/dired-read-file-name and it seemed promising, so I copied it to my `emacs` direcory and tried:

```
(require 'dired-read-file-name)
```

but I get error

```
error: Required feature `dired-read-file-name' was not provided
```

Comment: The normal way to do it is by calling `read-file-name`.  So you might want to explain which aspect of `read-file-name` doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Yes. If you want to read a file name from the user, use `read-file-name`. If you want to pick up a file name from the text at point, to serve as default value for the user input, use `find-file-at-point` and friends, from library `ffap.el`. If you want to let the user choose among a predetermined set of *absolute* file names using different directories ("paths"), use `completing-read`.

Comment: The github repository for `dired-read-file-name` is just a working example of various ways to use that concept, which is based on the function `dired-get-marked-files`.  `dired-get-marked-files` returns a list of file names that have been marked -- if only one file is being selected or marked, then the result is transformed into a string set to the variable `dired-one-file`.  I have configured the enter key to match the behavior I prefer, but that can be changed by the user with a little `elisp` coding.  The function `lawlist-save-as` is probably the closest example to the behavior you seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is not going to work because the source of `dired-read-file-name.el` does not have a `provides` expression. You might want to add:

```
(provide 'dired-read-file-name)
```

add the end of the file.

Alternatively, you can just `load` or more low-level `load-file`.

Also have a look at [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Loading-Files.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But it seems not to be what I was looking for.. I tried `(let (( file (dired-read-file-name "a"))) (message "%s" file))` hoping that it would return the filename that I selected in dired.. But instead it seems to open the file in a new buffer..

Comment: @HåkonHægland You might be interested in `dired-file-name-at-point` or the current value of the variable `file-name-at-point-functions`. Try `C-h v file-name-at-point-functions` for more information.

Comment: `provides` does not exist --- use `provide`.

Comment: I just added `(provide 'dired-read-file-name)` at the bottom of the source file.